# Maximum size of n-way associative cache?

Tags: caching, memory, memory-management, allocation, processor

When thinking about an n-way associative cache, is there a maximum number that *n* can be?

Example, if you had the following system:

[image]

Is it possible to determine the maximum number that *n* could be?

Comment: Cache lines are 64B on x86, so a 32 KB cache can straightforwardly only be up to 32K/64 = 512-way ("fully") associative. In actual x86 practice, only TLBs are fully associative, and other caches are no more than 16-way set-associative.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because of the way that this works, can the n be any integer between 1 and 512?

Comment: Cache-line size x # of ways x # sets = cache size, _precisely_. You can pick what you want for 3 out of those 4 values and calculate the last one. But on x86, cache-line size is 64B, and L1 cache is 32 KB, so what's left is # ways * # sets = 512. Because 512 is a power of 2, the two remaining numbers must also be powers of 2, and there are only 10 possibilities: 1x512, 2x256, 4x128, 8x64, 16x32, 32x16, 64x8, 128x4, 256x2 or 512x1. Take your pick.